# Eliminate Unwanted Characters in Ansible print

Tags: ansible

I store information in a varible HOST in ansible via register command. Then I am trying to print the contents(INFORMATION-1 to 3) of variable HOST line after line.

INFORMATION-1

INFORMATION-2

INFORMATION-3

Instead I am getting this result when printed.
[[u'INFORMATION-1'], [u'INFORMATION-2'], [u'INFORMATION-3']]

Any ideas how I eliminate those unwanted characters like brackets [ ], u and apostrophe(') and print the result in my desired format?

Answer (score 2):

> Any ideas how I eliminate those unwanted characters like brackets [ ], u and apostrophe(') and print the result in my desired format?

It's because whatever thing you are printing is actually a python `list` containing 3 python `list`s which themselves contain a unicode `str`

If you want them to be line delimited, then the `join()` filter will do that for you, and it should be safe to use a join for the inner lists, too, in case you ever end up with more than one value in the inner list:

```
# assuming your values are in a variable named "list_list_str"
- debug: var=the_output
  vars:
    the_output: '{{ list_list_str | map("join", "\n") | join("\n") }}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Matthew..I got stuck with workload so I replied late..I tried your suggestion..
# assuming your values are in a variable named "list_list_str"
- debug: var=the_output
  vars:
    the_output: '{{ list_list_str | map("join", "\n") | join("\n") }}'
  register: the_output

Result:
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [R1-192.168.X.X] => {
    "the_output": "INFORMATION-1\\nINFORMATION-2\\nINFORMATION-3"
}

Comment: Unwanted characters like brackets [ ], u and apostrophe(') are gone in ANSIBLE debug..But still when I tried to print it using my jinja html code below:


HTML JINJA:
<p><b>INTERFACE STATUS W/ DESCRIPTION:</b> <p> {{ the_output }} </p> <br></p>


Result:
[u'INFORMATION-1'] [u'INFORMATION-2'] [u'INFORMATION-3']


Still more or less the same problematic output as before..unwanted characters are there and desired format is not achieved..thanks

Comment: I find it very suspicious that the debug output is correct but you are unable to do it in your jinja2 template. Based only on that snippet, it looks like you are missing the `map("join", "\n")` to collapse those inner lists to be a `str`. Also, if you're looking to emit html, then use `join("<br/>")` for the final join, since the linebreaks won't matter in html